Anyone heard of the sefer Peri Netzach?
I saw this floating around recently regarding the earthquake, solar eclipse and the tensions between Israel and Iran, however, I've never heard of the sefer Peri Netzach, and nothing comes up about it online. Can anyone help me? Where I can find this sefer and if other people have heard of this? Thanks.


I suspect it's fake (but I will welcome being proven wrong).

There is a big Mekubal Rabbeinu Tzvi Hirsch T'zl, and he does have a chassidic sefer that has פרי in the title, but not נצח: https://hebrewbooks.org/14365. I have never learned it

No results on Hebrewbooks. I never heard of Rabbeinu Tzvi either.
